# Change Windows subsystem for Android downloads folder

Tags: windows, android, windows-11

I have an app sideloaded that I'm using to download files. I don't have much storage on my boot drive where the Windows Subsystem for Android is installed. The app I'm using downloads files to the Downloads folder on android. I was wondering if I can change where the android subsystem downloads folder actually is stored on my PC. I'd even be okay if there was some way to install the Windows Subsystem for Android elsewhere off my boot drive. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to install Windows Subsystem for Android on another drive when you are installing it from the Windows Store.